# How to install the QT module in my home directory?

Tags: qt

I need to install QT in my home directory. How can I install QT? I have tried to install and use that module with one example. While running that program it showed me that can't locate Qt.pm in @INC. Can anyone give me 
solution to solve this problem. I need proper url to download the QT and tutorial for QT.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What OS? I don't know what you mean by Qt module

Comment: Do you mean QuickTime (sometimes abbreviated QT) or the windowing toolkit Qt?

Comment: Also, you might get more answers on superuser.com.  I won't vote to close/move, because the answers could also be useful to programmers, but consider looking there for answers.  If it is a perl module, I would assume the instructions for installing the module are the same as for other modules (knowing nothing about perl modules).

Answer (score 1):

Just `apt-get install libqt-perl` if you're on Linux.